# Can't run PMD in windows

Tags: java, pmd

I was trying to run a simple java program in windows by running the command

```
pmd -d path-to-source\com\vaannila\domain\User.java -f text -R java-basic
```

and error showing up is as below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5/4/6\bin//\lib\asm-5/0/4/jar
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\bin..\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>               at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       Could not find the main class: C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\bin..\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar.  Program will exit.

Please help me with this to run the PMD

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in the script

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that `C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\bin..\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar` should have a slash between `bin` and `..`

Comment: If `C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar` exists, you should consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the asm-5.0.4.jar exists and the error is still coming. reporting a bug to?

Comment: Yes. The bug is that the proper directory separator is not being inserted into the path. There should be a slash between `bin` and `..` as I noted earlier.

Comment: It is separating correctly. As I pasting the stack trace in the question it is formatting the stack trace as above in stackoverflow @MadPhysicist

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of PMD (6.6.0)? The version you are using (5.4.6) is more than a year old... -> https://pmd.github.io/

Comment: actually, I was using Java 1.6 pmd 5.4.6 is the only compatible version for it

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem and I can't exactly make sense of the error message.

According to the error message, you have extracted PMD 5.4.6 into `C:\pmd`, so that the directory `C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6` exists. Inside this directory, there are two subdirectories: `bin` - which contains `pmd.bat` and `lib`, which contains the necessary jars to be put onto the classpath.

So, without further configuration of your system, you should be able to run simply `C:\pmd\pmd-5.4.6\bin\pmd.bat` in a command shell - you should see the help screen (and not the NoClassDefFound exception).

Can you try this? Does that work for you?
If not -> reinstall PMD as your installation seems to be broken somehow.

I see, that you are calling pmd with just using `pmd` - this works, if you are currently in the directory `C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\bin` - or if you add this directory to your `PATH` environment variable. Even if I do this, it works for me, regardless in which directory I'm in.

Did you configure something like the `PATH` environment variable?

I cannot make sense out of the error message - it claims, it can't find a class named "C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5/4/6\bin//\lib\asm-5/0/4/jar". This is not a class name, it looks like a manipulated class path - and also look at the mix of forward and backward slashes. The next part of the error is "C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\bin..\lib\asm-5.0.4.jar" - while it might seem to be right, that there is a slash missing - it still doesn't make sense. The error message said, that it could not find the main class - but the main class is called `net.soureforge.pmd.PMD`.

For reference, here is the [original content](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/pmd_releases/5.4.6/pmd-dist/src/main/scripts/pmd.bat) of `pmd.bat`:

```
@echo off
set TOPDIR=%~dp0..
set OPTS=
set MAIN_CLASS=net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD

java -classpath %TOPDIR%\lib\* %OPTS% %MAIN_CLASS% %*
```

Can you compare this with your `pmd.bat`?
I suspect, your file looks somehow different.

You can also run PMD without the batch file, e.g.:

`java -classpath C:\pmd\pmd-bin-5.4.6\lib\* net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD -d path-to-source\com\vaannila\domain\User.java -f text -R java-basic`

Does that work for you?

P.S.: It's true, that PMD 5.4.6 is the last one, that runs on Java 1.6. But that doesn't mean, that newer versions of PMD cannot analyze Java 1.6. code. You would just need a recent java runtime (e.g. java 10 or 11) for executing PMD and a separate JDK for building your project. PMD can analyze any version of java, it doesn't depend on the java version, it is running with.

Comment: I was running PMD 5.4.6, but probably on java 10 (not java 8 or 6). @nsuriya239

Comment: well thanks, @adangel. I was using Java 6 for PMD 5.4.6 and it is not supporting and I moved to PMD 5.3.8 It supports Java 6